# Java Spring Jpa saveAll method fails if one object hits a unique constaint

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa

I am currently working in a spring boot project where i need to save new objects in the database.
I have created an ArrayList where I add all these objects to be stored.

`List<Visit> visitsToBeStored = new ArrayList<>();`

`visitsToBeStored.add(visitService.constructVisit(customer));`

```
//VisitService method
public Visit constructVisit(Customer customer){
        Visit visit = new Visit();
        visit.setCustomer(customer);
        return visit;
    }
```

```
visitRepository.saveAll(visitsToBeStored);
```

```
//Visit entity
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@Table(name="visits" , indexes = {@Index(name="customer_createdDate_index", columnList="Customer_Id,created_at", unique=true)})
@NoArgsConstructor
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
public class Visit {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(unique=true, nullable=false, precision=10)
    private int id;
    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="Customer_Id", nullable = false)
    private Customer customer;
    @CreatedDate
    @Column(name="created_at", nullable = false)
    private Date createdAt;
}
```

```
//Customer entity
@Entity(name="customers")
@Table(name="Customers")
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Customer implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="Customer_Id", unique=true, nullable=false, precision=10)
    private int customerId;
    @Column(name="Mobile_Number", precision=20)
    private Long mobileNumber;
    @Column(name="Send_Date")
    private Timestamp sendDate;
    @Column(name="Valid", precision=3, columnDefinition = "TINYINT(3)")
    private Short valid;
    @Column(name="Pending", precision=3, columnDefinition = "TINYINT(4)")
    private Short pending;
    @Column(name="u_number", precision=20)
    private Long unumber;
    @Column(name="Email", length=45)
    private String email;


}
```

The Visit class has unique constaint for customer.
My problem occurs when the list has an object with a customer that is already persisted in the database.
In that case the whole query fails.
I would like to save all other visitsToBeStored objects except these that have failed because of the existence of constaint.
Is there a way to do this with a jpa save method ? 
I prefer not checking the existence of the object before addition in the list. This is my worst solution in this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: would u please add both entities `Customer` and `Visit` in ur question to suggest correct way to do so

Comment: also add the visitRepository.saveAll code